# Set axis properties after plot is created

Tags: python, seaborn

I am using seaborn and trying to create and then edit plots. I'm somewhat new to Python and what I'd like to do is something like this:

1) Create plot: `g = sns.lmplot(x, y, df, hue=z); #with seaborn imported as sns`

2) `g.style = "whitegrid" #I know this cannot be done as written, but how?`

3) `g.Font = "times new roman" #Same comment...`

Anyway, I hope this makes sense. I appreciate the help.

Comment: What is your expected output and what is your actual output or error?

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot create the figure first?

Comment: There is not a specific reason that I cannot create the figure first. The reason I asked is that occasionally it is useful to plot data, and then mess with the aesthetics without having to replot everything.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just set style prior to creating your plot e.g. after loading the package

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="whitegrid", font='Times New Roman')
```

[Link to seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the attributes for `sns` as you go from one plot to other.

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)
y = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)
z = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=10)
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'x':x,
    'y':y,
    'z':z
})
sns.set(style="whitegrid", font='Times New Roman')
g = sns.lmplot('x', 'y', df, hue='z')
plt.show()

sns.set(style="dark", font='Arial')
g = sns.lmplot('x', 'y', df, hue='z')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]